# Photon Unity Networking: Не получается вывести ник игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу установить ник для игрока и в последующем его отобразить.
Еще до подключения к комнате я устанавливаю ник таким образом:

```
PhotonNetwork.NickName = "My name";
```

А вытаскиваю ник в самой игре уже таким образом:

```
Debug.log("Nickname = " + gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>().Owner.Nickname);
```

Но в консоли выводится порядковый номер, например число 1. 
Почему так происходит? Как вывести ник?

Answer (score 0):

```
PhotonNetwork.player.NickName = "Player #1";
//
Debug.log("Nickname = " + gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>().owner.NickName);
```